# Sending file to server API using fetch POST method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to send .xml file from my PC to a server, but im getting this error:
**POST https://localhost:44391/api/edit net::ERR_ABORTED 415**

File state

```
const [file, setFile] = useState();
```

Input and button

```
 <input type="file" id="file" onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])} />
 <button onClick={send}>DASD</button>
```

Onclick function

```
const send = async () => {
        if (file) {
            let formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', file);
            console.log(formData);
            await fetch("https://localhost:44391/api/edit", 
            { method: "POST", body: formData });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the content type from the header, as the content type is not `'text/xml` it should be `multipart/form-data`.

Fetch api will automatically add the header based on the content. Which will be something `Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=—-WebKitFormBoundaryfgtsKTYLsT7PNUVD`

```
const send = async () => {
  if (file) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    console.log(formData);
    await fetch("https://localhost:44391/api/edit", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you check what the media type set in backend api. And open the browser console and check what media type is attached with the api call.

Comment: I used debugger and server isn't even opening the POST controller. I don't know how to check media type attached with the api call.

Comment: Open the developer console and go to network tab the click on the request, you will the content type under header

Comment: Ok got it, here it is: content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySVLxzc2dxArO0AQg

Comment: Looks ok , No issue with your code, you have to check your backend code.